# Syntax Highlighter Around A Div Element

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

I am using the syntax highlighter plugin and I want to always have it applied to a specific div area.  The div's content will change based on a on-click hyperlink. How can I enclose the syntax highlighter script tag around the "mydiv" element at all times?

```
<script>
    function viewCode() {
        $('#mydiv').load('euler/_48.py');   
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="viewCode();return true">View Code</a>

<div id="mydiv">
    my div's initial content
</div>

<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: js"><![CDATA[
    //always apply this script to mydiv
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With syntaxHighlighter, you cannot highlight arbitrary elements on the page, so we will stick to the `script` method instead.

First, give the script and anchor tag an `id`, like

```
<a href="#" id="show_code">Show Code</a>
<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: js" id="highlighted"></script>
```

Then, use this to load the contents when the user clicks on the link

```
$('#show_code').click(function(){
  $.get('euler/_48.py', function(data){
    $('#highlighted').html('<![CDATA[' + data + ']]>');
    SyntaxHighligher.highlight();
  });
});
```

Remember that the usual method to use syntexhighlighter.js would not work here because the `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` function only binds the `highlight()` function to the `onload` event, so you will have to call that function yourself every time the page updates, by adding a call to the `SyntaxHighligher.highlight()` function everytime you update the page.

---

Alternatively, I'd usually recommend the `pre` method. Its almost the same as above, but we use the `pre` element instead and use the `text()` jQuery function to get the escaping done correctly. Using the `pre` element:

```
<pre class="brush: js" id="highlighted"></pre>
```

With this piece of Javascript

```
$.get('euler/_48.py', function(data){
  $('#highlighted').text(data);
  SyntaxHighligher.highlight();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I apply that to #mydiv? Is it just $('#mydiv').get instead of my $('#mydiv').load? I've been trying your suggestion with what I just said but it's not working for me at the moment.

Comment: @medikgt You can't, and shouldn't - like I said in the first line, you shouldn't try to use syntaxHighlighter on *any* HTML element - only `script` or `pre`. The `.load()` syntax is special, in that it is actually called from the element.

Comment: @medikgt I think you are confusing certain things. You need to clarify what you're trying to do here. What I thought you were doing was to load the contents of external files into a `div`, then apply syntax highlighting to it, right?

Comment: @medikgt Then you need to place the code I gave you into the click event handler, wait while I modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call HighlightAll method

Example:

`dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');`

Sultan